# D3.js: How to Center svg map after Drag, Zoom, or MouseMove Events

Tags: d3.js, mousemove

My map projection and display goes awry when users drag, move the map (see:  https://realtimeceap.brc.tamus.edu).

For example (duplicate event):
 1. Select a field condition from dropdownlist.
 2. Select a State from dropdownlist.
 3. Select a County from dropdownlist.
 4. Drag the map or move the mousewheel.
 5. Then, select another State from dropdownlist.  The map is not centered at the middle of the svg element and the scale is off, instead of scale 1.

Appreciate any help.

I reset the map on selecting a state as follows:

```
function resetMap() {
    svg = d3.select("#svgMap2");

    var w = 728;
    var h = 500;

    var project = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
        .scale(1000)
        .translate([w / 2, h / 2]);

    var t = project.translate(); // the projection's default translation
    var scale = project.scale;

    //reset all features to original scale
    d3.select("#svgMap2").select("#counties").selectAll(".county")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")
        .style("stroke", "#808080")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + t[0] + "," + t[1] + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

Comment: Could you share some usable code for us to try and find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Been working on this for a while and found the solution is so simple.  I needed to reset the g element's *transform* attribute to null to redefine it.  The id of my svg = *svgMap2* and the id of my g element = *counties*.  BTW, I'm using D3.js version 4.

```
function resetMap() {
    var k = 1;
    var t = [0, 0];
    svg = d3.select("#svgMap2")  

    d3.select("#svgMap2").select("#counties").selectAll(".county").classed("active", false);
    d3.select("#counties").attr("transform", null);

    svg.select("#counties").selectAll(".county")  //must use svg or it disables pan, zoom
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")
        .style("stroke", "#808080")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + t[0] + "," + t[1] + ")scale(" + k + ")");
}
```